# What am I doing wrong with Tailwind CSS centering?

Tags: css, tailwind-css, centering

EDIT: the wrong behavior was due to a missed `</div>` (see screenshots).
Thank you so much for your patience -_-

I'm struggling with horizontal item centering in Tailwind CSS.
Let's take a div with two children like so:

```
<div class="flex flex-row w-60 justify-center items-center space-x-10 border-2">
  <p>text 1</p>
  <p>text 2</p>
</div>
```

and weirdly enough, it's not centered!

The problem, I found out, is that the `x-spacing` is added between the two objects but is eating away at the space before the first object, so that the leftmost object gets "pushed" more to the left as `space-x` increases.

This is centered:

```
<div class="flex flex-row w-60 justify-center items-center space-x-0 border-2">
  <p>text 1</p>
  <p>text 2</p>
</div>
```

Result:
[image]

this is not:

```
<div class="flex flex-row w-60 justify-center items-center space-x-16 border-2">
  <p>text 1</p>
  <p>text 2</p>
</div>
```

Result:
[image]

Does anyone know a solution to this? Is it a bug or am I just expecting the wrong behavior from `justify-items`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies with the use of `w-60` which sets the `<div>` to 15rem wide. This results in your two `<p>` tags being centered inside the allowed 15rem, but since the `<div>` is left-aligned, the items are not properly centered.

You can remove that class to center the two `<p>` tags as required. Alternatively, you can add another `<div>` tag with the `w-60` class to get the centered effect you're after.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tailwindcss/2.2.15/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class="w-60 bg-red-50">This div is 15rem wide</div>

<hr class="my-5">

<!-- 15rem container div -->
<div class="flex w-60 bg-red-50 justify-center items-center space-x-16 border-2">
    <p>text 1</p>
    <p>text 2</p>
</div>


<hr class="my-5">

<!-- Additional div wrapper with the w-60 class applied. -->
<div class="w-60 mx-auto">
    <div class="flex bg-red-50 justify-center items-center space-x-16 border-2">
        <p>text 1</p>
        <p>text 2</p>
    </div>
</div>
<hr class="my-5">


<!-- 100% wide container div -->
<div class="flex bg-red-50 justify-center items-center space-x-16 border-2">
    <p>text 1</p>
    <p>text 2</p>
</div>
```

The `flex-row` class is redundant since it's the default behaviour, so I've removed it from the code.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand- isn't there enough space in the 15rem div to allow for the two items to be centered? Btw I need to set a fixed width to the div.

Comment: The `<p>` tags are centered, but since the `<div>` tag is only 15rem wide, it doesn't look correctly centered against the full width of the page. Unless I'm not fully understanding your question? I'll edit my answer to include an example of what I mean.

Comment: @marcotrevi I've added additional examples to explain the implications of the `w-60` (`width: 15rem`) class.

Comment: i found the bug (see edited question). Do you still think that the w-60 poses a problem? I still don't understand if setting a fixed with is a problem or not!

Comment: It's up to you to determine if it's working as expected. I did notice the  invalid closing `</div>` tag in your question earlier, but assumed that was a copy/paste error rather than the cause of the issue you're facing.

Comment: Yes, it's working as expected- my bad!

Comment: haha, it's all good, so long as we got the problem sorted. :)

Answer (score 2):

Did you expected this?

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tailwindcss/2.2.15/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="flex justify-between">
  <div class="flex px-2 ">text 1</div>
  <div class="flex px-2 ">text 2</div>
  <div class="flex px-2 ">text 3</div>
</div>
```

If not, please describe in more detail what you expect the result to be!

Comment: In my example above, I'd expect that the white space between text 1 and text 2 to be centered! I don't understand what is being horizontally centered in that case

Comment: You will center the div.flex.justify-between block ? then you wrapped it with: `<div class="max-w-6xl mx-auto px-4">` Hope i understand you well?

Comment: I probably don't understand how divs work. I assumed that the horizontal centering is made wrt to the parent div. Isn't that the case? What is being centered in my second example?

Comment: Your parent div width  (w-60) was the small "problem". Try to remove the w-60 class and see the result. @Kirk Beard explained very well.

Comment: I found the stupidest bug. Thank you but I think the w-60 was not the problem after all